# Help setting up ubuntu 16.04.1

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation

Hey all this is my first post so excuse me if I seem ignorant/annoying

I have a PC that I built that normally runs windows 10, but I am trying to move to Ubuntu, but I also need the windows partition to remain for program compatibility

I have multiple disk, a 256 GB SSD that I want to install Ubuntu on, it also holds my windows partition, I already shrunk that partition and have ~95GB for Ubuntu, as well as a 2 TB HDD That mainly holds games, a 1 TB HDD for backups and...more games and finally I have a 500 GB HDD for...you guessed it games (I have a problem ok...) when booting from a USB I get to the install screen for Ubuntu and I get as far as the Installation type screen. I have the option to Erase the disk and install Ubuntu, which I don't want to do because 1. I'm not sure what disk it'd install on, and 2. I don't want to lose everything on the drives

When I go to the something else screen I got pretty confused at all the options, eventually I was able to find the partition I want Ubuntu installed on but when I click it I see the option to adjust the partition size as well as 
Type for the new partition Primary or Logical, I assume I want Primary and also 
Location for the new partition Beginning of the Space or End of the space, I don't understand the difference, I assume it doesn't matter to much
There's also The Use As option, I see a bunch of options when I click the drop down Ext4 journaling file system, as well as Ext3&2 journaling systems, plus Fat16+32 file system, swap area and Physical volume for encryption plus a few others that I won't take room listing I think this post is already far to long

and finally mount point...what is it? does it matter what I select? there's /home /boot /usr /opt plus I can enter my own....

So this post is a lot longer than I was expecting...sorry about that I guess the simplest way I can ask this is, can someone show me a absolute beginners guide to installing Ubuntu on a multi drive system, though I have experience with technology I have next to none when it comes to ubuntu or linux

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows 10 is abit fickle animal compared to previous versions.

First, disable secure boot in Windows https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/commercialize/manufacture/desktop/disabling-secure-boot

Then if you have Windows 10 64 pre-installed OEM, you'll probably have a UEFI partition, your Windows 10 system partition and a recovery partition. Some if these maybe hidden so count your memory on your partitions.

Backup, of course.

Resize system & swap partitions to allow what you need.

Download ubuntu & burn iso, make bootable. (You've obviously done this)

The "along side Windows" should appear.

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to unplug all your drives (important!!) ***except*** the one that you want Ubuntu installed on, the SSD in this case, and select the option called something like "Install alongside Windows" when you get the the partitioning point. It'll handle partitioning everything for you and get the bootloader installed where it should go.

Comment: I unplugged all extra HDDs but it brings me to the same screen, I ended up choosing /home for the mount point but it's saying No root file system is defined please correct this from the partitioning menu

Comment: Doesn't it give you [this](http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-GMyMgXW8IWc/Vjfb1nsFDTI/AAAAAAAAKww/c5Whc7TC1cM/s1600/ubuntuinstall5.png) screen? I pulled it from the first link on Google for "Install Ubuntu alongside Windows 10", which I found [here](http://www.everydaylinuxuser.com/2015/11/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-alongside.html).

Comment: No it doesn't, it shows the exact same screen as when I had all my hard drives plugged in

Comment: The screen should not be dependent on your hard drives being plugged in or not, I just had you unplug them so it did not write over any of your data and cause it's good practice to do so when dealing with something that is creating partitions without your interaction.


What options does it give you when you get to the screen that has the 'Something Else' option that you mentioned?

Comment: To try and help I just took a photo of the two screens here [link](http://imgur.com/6fYjJLy) and [link](http://imgur.com/fs8ciyE) that's what it's showing under the 'something else' section

Comment: I am talking about the screen that actually says 'Something Else', not the one that it leads to.

Comment: Back a screen or two from where you are now.

Comment: [Here](http://imgur.com/pC856L6) sorry about that

Comment: Before you go any further, make sure you can still boot into windows. Shut down the system and try to reboot without the USB plugged in.

Comment: Confirmed, without a usb in windows 10 boots without an issue

Comment: Good. Now you'll want to disable Fast Startup in Windows. This is in the power options. What it does is mark the Windows partitions as 'In Use' and is likely the reason that the Ubuntu installer does not see it.

Comment: I did that, ran a .bat file from cmd but still same screen

Comment: What .bat file did you run? There should have just been a checkbox in the power settings.

Comment: There was no option in power options even once I clicked the option to show all, but still nothing showed, though I think that's because I have it so windows doesn't create a hibernation file, supposedly that stops it from showing

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your two linked images and your question, you have a 95 Gig partition that you have formatted for Linux.  You don't have to but I would recommend that you shrink it to about 80 and make a 15 gig swap partition.  You don't have to make it now, you can actually make a swap partition later on a different drive.

Making the swap partition available during the install will facilitate the install process to configure it for startup.

On the `do something else` option, choose the Linux partition that you have create as the `/` mounting point.  Then continue with the install.  The process is automatic and seamless.

It'll install on the selected partition.  If you supply a swap partition it'll use that for increased performance.

By the way, you can do the same thing with all your drives plugged in.  Just be particular where you assign the installation.  It'll only use the space that you select.

As far as the partition type, choose `Ext4`.

The partitions that you see that are other formats are the partitions where you have your Windows files stored.  As long as you don't choose those partitions for the install, they won't be touched.

The benefit of having all your other drives plugged in will be that, all the other OS installs will be available as an alternate boot option.  If you don't care to boot into any of those other Windows installations, then it wouldn't matter whether you have them plugged in or not.